# How to modfiy environment variable in GNU makefile

Tags: linux, shell, makefile

filename : "**dev**"

```
export CFLAGS="-g -O2 -Wall -std=gnu99 -fno-strict-aliasing -D_GNU_SOURCE"
export CXXFLAGS="-g -O2 -Wall -fno-strict-aliasing -D_GNU_SOURCE"
```

Before I compiled my project I used the source dev, so that **echo $CFLAGS  $CXXFLAGS** will be the value I assign to it.

But how do I to change the environment variables in a Makefile? I tried the follow, but failed.

```
[root@centos-linux-10 make]# cat Makefile 
all:
    export CFLAGS="-O2 -Wall -std=gnu99 -fno-strict-aliasing -D_GNU_SOURCE"
    export CXXFLAGS="-O2 -Wall -fno-strict-aliasing -D_GNU_SOURCE"

    @echo $(CFLAGS)
    @echo $(CXXFLAGS)

[root@centos-linux-10 make]# make 
export CFLAGS="-O2 -Wall -std=gnu99 -fno-strict-aliasing -D_GNU_SOURCE"
export CXXFLAGS="-O2 -Wall -fno-strict-aliasing -D_GNU_SOURCE"
-g -O2 -Wall -std=gnu99 -fno-strict-aliasing -D_GNU_SOURCE
-g -O2 -Wall -fno-strict-aliasing -D_GNU_SOURCE
[root@centos-linux-10 make]#
```

After few try,I got this.In makefile I echo the CFLAGS and CXXFLAGS，they are the new value,after make,why the value of thme went back???

```
[root@centos-linux-10 make]# cat Makefile 
export CFLAGS="-O2 -Wall -std=gnu99 -fno-strict-aliasing -D_GNU_SOURCE"
export CXXFLAGS="-O2 -Wall -fno-strict-aliasing -D_GNU_SOURCE"

all:

    @echo $(CFLAGS)
    @echo $(CXXFLAGS)

[root@centos-linux-10 make]# echo $CFLAGS
-g -O2 -Wall -std=gnu99 -fno-strict-aliasing -D_GNU_SOURCE
[root@centos-linux-10 make]# echo $CXXFLAGS
-g -O2 -Wall -fno-strict-aliasing -D_GNU_SOURCE
[root@centos-linux-10 make]# 
[root@centos-linux-10 make]# make
-O2 -Wall -std=gnu99 -fno-strict-aliasing -D_GNU_SOURCE
-O2 -Wall -fno-strict-aliasing -D_GNU_SOURCE
[root@centos-linux-10 make]# 
[root@centos-linux-10 make]# echo $CFLAGS
-g -O2 -Wall -std=gnu99 -fno-strict-aliasing -D_GNU_SOURCE
[root@centos-linux-10 make]# echo $CXXFLAGS
-g -O2 -Wall -fno-strict-aliasing -D_GNU_SOURCE
```

Comment: The first export command is run in one shell, the second in another, the echo commands are run in two more shells.  What you do in the first shell does not affect any of the other shells.  You could try messing with `.ONESHELL:` to make the test 'work'.  However, that's not the solution to your problem.  You can set CFLAGS etc in the `makefile`.  You can use `make -e` to change the prioritization of environment and settings in the makefile.

Answer (score 1):

First, each line of a recipe is run in it's own shell as @JonathanLeffler mentioned.  Each time a shell exits, it forgets about all its variables (there's some very good security reasons for doing this).   So a variable set in one line of a recipe cannot be accessed on the next line.    One of the more common ways to get around this is to use only one line for your recipe.   I should point out that you're also using `$(CFLAGS)` to try to refer to a bash variable.   Make will expand the `$(CFLAGS)` to its internal variable before even passing it to bash, so in your example you're not even using the bash variable.

To illustrate:

```
foo:
    @SOMEVAR=hello; \
     echo $@:$$SOMEVAR

bar:
    @SOMEVAR=hello;
    @echo $@:$$SOMEVAR

MAKEVAR:=goodbye
foobar:
    @echo "$@:$(MAKEVAR)"
```

Then you get:

```
tmp> make foo bar foobar
foo:hello
bar:
foobar:goodbye
```

notice the ';' and '\' at the end of the first line of the `foo` recipe.  The `\` concatenates the two recpies lines into one, and the `;` tells bash to run as two separate commands.   Also notice the lack of `@` symbol on the second line, as bash doesn't understand the `@`.  Finally, notice in the `foobar` recipe, there's only a single `$` in front of the make variable, which means its expanded by the makefile, but two `$$`'s in front of the `foo` and `bar` variants (Which expand to a single `$` before being passed to bash).